# SMART ‘Reported Uncorrect’ field

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

When smartd sends an email about the amount of Offline_Uncorrectable sectors has increased, they do not increase Reallocated_Sector_Ct after manual fix (erasing with dd for example), as one might expect. So it seems that the drive remapped(?) the bad sectors, but that wasn’t reflected in SMART attributes. Then how do I know that the limit of remapping area is near?

Though there is another field that reflects the change, it’s the subject Reported_Uncorrect, but is always had 0 as Threshold and 1 as a Value of the field itself, so I think, it’s not the field to rely on.

The subject disk is Seagate ST31000528AS.

Drive increases Reallocated_Sector_Ct amount when it can do it by itself. But that value is small in comparison with one of Reported_Uncorrect.

Comment: It does not necessarily automatically remap the sectors.  I would recommend spinrite or mhdd.  Either should remap the bad sectors. mhdd has an option you have to turn on to engage remapping.

Comment: You know, in the end it is the drive who remaps sectors. Automatically or forced by dd or your beloved mhdd.